# List append or insert in jupyter notebook creating duplicate elements

Tags: python, list, jupyter-notebook, append

When I try to do a list append in a jupyter notebook it creates a duplicate element.

It doesn't happen when I try on console

Same thing with 'insert' or 'extend'

```
test = []
test.append('a')
print(test)
['a', 'a']
```

Screenshot:

[image: Print]

Comment: Is that in the same cell? If not the `test` list might already be defined and you append to existing list, that's it.

Comment: @Gameplay - But `test` was reassigned a new empty list. If this is the exact code, there is something wrong with the tool. First step is to fully exit jupyter and try again.

Comment: I think an image of the notebook showing this strange behavior would be useful. It could be that you have multiple cells and are running the append cell twice.

Comment: Post updated with print

Comment: Where are `In[5]` and `Out[5]`?

Comment: Following on @mkrieger1 's question, always restart the kernel and run all cells before assuming you aren't hitting the 'hidden state' problem you can have with Jupyter, search for 'hidden state' [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-case-against-the-jupyter-notebook-d4da17e97243). Look under the 'Kernel' on the menubar for a way to do that 'Restart Kernel and Run All Cells' easily. Doing that routinely will save you a lot of headaches.